# Empty CardList object in Java

Tags: java

I have a slight problem right now.

Currently I have two classes. One called CardList and another called Trick.
The CardList is what it sounds like, it is an object that declares itself as an arraylist and had multiple methods in it one that is add. Trick is supposed to be an CardList and extends the CardList class.

```
private CardList aTrick;
private Suit trumpSuit;

public Trick(Bid pContract)
{   
    aTrick = new CardList();
    this.trumpSuit = pContract.getSuit();
}
```

At the moment, whenever I use the add method within Trick, the CardList remains empty.

For example.

```
trick = new Trick(new Bid(7, Card.Suit.HEARTS));
trick.add(aJD);
```

The list remains empty.
Any help would be appreciated.

The add method is within the CardList class.
All it does is add cards normally to an arrayList. Nothing special.

Comment: Update the add method to alter the list.  Obviously....

Comment: Some more info on `Trick.add` would be helpful

Comment: If you show real code, you can get real answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Trick` is suppose to extend `CardList` why do you have a reference to the `CardList` in the `Trick` class, this is not inheritance...

```
public class Trick extends CardList {
    // Implementation specific options here
}
```

Would be "extending" `CardList`

Comment: +1 extending will solve this issue according to my opinion. Assuming atleast `CardList` method does the add :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your constructor of `Trick` makes it empty

```
  aTrick = new CardList();
```

You should initialize it somewhere else if you want to use it this way.
Also you will need to implement `aTrick.add()` inside `trick.add(aJD)`

Comment: Umm, you might want to read that a little closer, the constructor makes no use of the `CardList` when it's constructed. I'd be more worried about this mysterious `add` method (ps, that's not to say you're wrong though ;))

Comment: I think your solution should work I missed the part in which it is supposed to extend.

Comment: The problem is in the wording of the question and the lack of information. You might still be right ;)

Comment: I will keep the solution then :)